# Не вижу view элемент на экране, хотя он должен быть

Tags: android, android-xml

Имеется разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".jobAGENT.JobsList">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyJobList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="@string/no_jobs"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_t"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/job_list_t"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Проблема в том, что при скрытии `SwipeRefreshLayout` я не вижу `TextView` и это по-моему не очень нормально. Да, я знаю что в xml стоит `inVisible` , но я из активности меняю этот параметр на Visible ,а список скрываю. Я подумал может у него все-таки с видимостью проблемы и поэтому его не видно на экране:

```
Log.i("m", (emptyList.visibility==View.VISIBLE).toString())
```

, но в логах было `true` и я решил, что проблема где-то в другом месте. Я просмотрел всю активность и не нашел больше нигде регулирования видимости этого элемента и я, честно говоря, в замешательстве, ведь все должно быть нормально видно. Дальше я посмотрел на `LayoutInspector` и там тоже есть этот элемент, хотя я не вижу текста в `textView` (вдруг кто будет спрашивать - текст там есть и цвет его тоже нормальный). Дальше, я убрал вообще в XML тег видимости и опять таки я ничего не увидел. Мое допущение - `textView` находится под `SwipeRefreshLayout`, но в таком случае он бы стал видимым когда этот макет скрывается командой `Gone` из активности. Короче, у меня кончились идеи.

Comment: Должно работать) Может быть поможет, если прописать констрэинты для TextView? Только у него их нет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне тоже кажется что должно работать, но почему-то не работает :( привязки я пробовал и не помогло (

Comment: Ну... может ещё попробовать фон какой-то вьюхе поставить? Чтобы точно убедиться, что у неё видимость не проставлена как-то не так?